# import data from .txt file into mySQL table

Tags: mysql, database

I have created the table in mysql and the table is created Now I want to insert the data into the table but the issue is that the data which I want to inset into that particular table is saved with me in a separate text file , the same data I want to insert into the table , Please advise how I can insert the data of the text file into that particular table .I have also downloaded the sql gui browser tool also, Please advise.

Comment: @MikeBrant I have created the table I was looking for solution through some grapical tool like mysql gui tool but haven't found anything yet , Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding

Either you should use any programming language to read your text file and insert it

or

if you would like to do avoid the programming lang then you can import the text file using sql comments in the file with those data to  your db as mysql import process.

[Document](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqlimport.html)

[More Info](http://blogs.devart.com/dbforge/how-to-import-data-to-mysql-from-text-file.html)